# RegExp for searching a comma delimited string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sorted list of about 2500 unique keywords delimited with commas. Keywords are in English and can be of several words separated by spaces.
I need to search incrementally words input from an input tag.

```
/,a[^,]+(?=,)/gi  this returns all keywords starting with an "a" or whatever typed in input tag.
```

It works very well indeed, but it will return the leading comma as well.
 Demo https://regex101.com/r/4zRV12/1/

I know is easy to remove this comma afterwords from the matches, still wonder if there is a way to do it in one pass.
Here my Test page javascript

```
 function reg(p){
   patt=","+p+"[^,]+(?=,)";
   var regex= new RegExp(patt, "gi");
   var k = '';
   cnt=0;
   var res;
   while ((res = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
   k=k + "<a href='#' onclick='fill(this.innerHTML)';>"+res[0]+"</a><br>";
   cnt++;
   }
   k=cnt+"<br>"+k;
   document.getElementById("kword").innerHTML = k;  
  }
 function fill(w){
  document.getElementById("searchTxt").value = w;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4zRV12/3 Try `/(?<=,)a[^,]+/gi`

Comment: Instead of sending keywords as comma-separated string, use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed little bit in your regex,you can use this regex:

```
(?<=,)a[^,]+(?=,)
```

Comment: This might not work if the first word in the csv list starts with `a`.  The lookbehind would not see a comma and so would skip over the first term.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - in that case we can use this regex `(?:^a|(?<=,)a)[^,]+(?=,)`, but this is not his requirment i think. Thanks for you feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you should be able to just split the sorted list by commas, and then iterate over the result array, searching for the input:

```js
var keywords = "apple, ant, baseball, golf, surfing, teapot";
var array = keywords.split(/,\s*/);
var pattern = /^a/i;
for (var j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
    console.log(array[j] + (array[j].match(pattern) ? ' - match' : ''));
}
```

The pattern I used would match all keywords starting with `a` and followed by anything.  If you need to short-circuit after finding the first match in your sorted list, then you can just break out of the above `for` loop.

Comment: Suggestions: `/^a/i` is enough. I will also use `i` flag as OP has used it in original regex. Use `RegExp#test` instead of `String#match`. And **if** keywords are sorted, `break` out on first non-match after last match.

Answer (score 0):

You could use capture groups like this

```
(?:,)(a[^,]+)
```

Then in your javascript code you can iterate over the matches using

```js
var myString = ",Abdul Rahim,Abhakara Kiartivonses,Airavata,Akha,Amanpuri,Amari Atrium";
var myRegexp = new RegExp("(?:,)(a[^,]+)", "gi");
while( match = myRegexp.exec(myString)) 
{
  console.log(match[1])
}
```